# Aligning Text Left, Center, and Right with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I've got some text on my canvas and I'm trying to use buttons to align the text to the left, center, and right in it's  my fabricjs canvas. I saw [this example](https://codepen.io/shershen08/pen/JGepQv) but would prefer to use buttons over a select box. I've tried a bunch and am feeling pretty lost.

```js
var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

document.getElementById('text-align').onclick = function() {
            canvas.getActiveObject().setTextAlign(this.value);
            canvas.renderAll();
        };
        
        var text = new fabric.IText('Some demo\nText', {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fontSize: 22,
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: true,
  cornerStyle: 'circle',
  lockRotation: true,
  hasControls: true,
  lockUniScaling: true,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
})
canvas.add(text);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button id="text-align" value="left">Left</button>
<button id="text-align" value="center">Center</button>
<button id="text-align" value="right">Right</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the fabric code. Rather it was because you were using the same id for all the buttons. `document.getElementById` returns only the first instance and therefore your click listener was getting added to the 'left' button only

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
};

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

document.querySelectorAll('.text-align').forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.onclick = function() {
    canvas.getActiveObject().setTextAlign(this.value);
    canvas.renderAll();
  };
})

var text = new fabric.IText('Some demo\nText', {
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fontSize: 22,
  hasBorders: true,
  hasControls: true,
  cornerStyle: 'circle',
  lockRotation: true,
  hasControls: true,
  lockUniScaling: true,
  hasRotatingPoint: false,
})
canvas.add(text);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button class="text-align" value="left">Left</button>
<button class="text-align" value="center">Center</button>
<button class="text-align" value="right">Right</button>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```